# Which PHP file would a custom theme_link function go into?

Tags: theming

For some Taxonomy term pages I would like to change the "Read More"

link to "More info". Using theme developer, I see it’s using the `theme_link` function and gives a candidate function name.

If I re-write this function, in which `PHP` file would I put this custom function?

Answer (score 1):

[`theme_link()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/theme_link) doesn't use a template file. You can override its output by placing your own theme function in your theme's **template.php** file:

```
function MYTHEME_link($variables) {
  //Alter this as you see fit
  return '<a href="' . check_plain(url($variables ['path'], $variables ['options'])) . '"' . drupal_attributes($variables ['options']['attributes']) . '>' . ($variables ['options']['html'] ? $variables ['text'] : check_plain($variables ['text'])) . '</a>';
}
```